# Dúvidas em um exercicio em C

Tags: c

Eu estou fazendo um exercício que pede:

> Escreva um algoritmo que receba um arranjo A de 10 elementos e obtenha
> um arranjo F cujos componentes são os fatoriais dos respectivos
> componentes de V.

Meu código ficou assim, onde eu errei? Ele não está lendo os fatoriais:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int vetorA[10],vetorfat[10];
    int i, fatorial;

    printf("Digite os valores do vetor A: \n");

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        scanf("%d",&vetorA[i]);
    }

    printf("O vetor fatorial dos respectivos componentes ficara: \n");

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        for(fatorial = 1; vetorA[i] > 1; vetorA[i] = vetorA[i] -1){
    
            fatorial = fatorial*vetorA[i];
            vetorfat[i] = vetorfat[fatorial];
    
            printf("%d ", vetorfat[fatorial]);
    
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Há dois problemas: são eles o acesso ao índice do vetor `vetorfat` e o `printf` que exibirá mais números do que deseja por estar dentro do segundo laço de repetição, responsável por apenas calcular os números fatoriais.

O problema de não conseguir ver os números calculados está no fato de tentar acessar o índice com o valor da variável `fatorial`:

```
vetorfat[i] = vetorfat[fatorial];
```

O vetor `vetorfat` não tem tantos itens quanto declarou inicialmente. Ou seja, **no momento em que um número fatorial calculado se torna maior do que 9 (nove), não há como acessar um índice maior do que o valor "pré determinado de itens - 1"; o programa não consegue acessar a região de memória solicitada e resulta no término de sua execução**.

Assim que isso é corrigido, notará que a saída dos números vai exibir muito mais itens do que existe no vetor `vetorA` inicial. Isso acontece porque o `printf` está dentro do laço de repetição que deveria estar responsável por apenas calcular o fatorial do número atual:

```
    for(fatorial = 1; vetorA[i] > 1; vetorA[i] = vetorA[i] -1){

        // ...

        printf("%d ", vetorfat[fatorial]); 

   }
```

Não é necessário ter um vetor `vetorfat` a mais, dado que está apenas querendo exibir os valores do vetor inicial. O laço interno onde calcula o valor fatorial teria apenas o cálculo e o `printf` ficaria fora do mesmo, exibindo apenas o valor da variável `fatorial`:

```
for (fatorial = 1; vetorA[i] > 1; vetorA[i] = vetorA[i] - 1) {
    fatorial = fatorial * vetorA[i];
}

printf("%d ", fatorial);
```

Utilizando o código acima, a saída para os valores de 1 a 10 seria:

```
O vetor fatorial dos respectivos componentes ficara:                    
1 2 6 24 120 720 5040 40320 362880 3628800
```